# Turn a CSS Linear Gradient Into An HTML Bootstrap Button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, linear-gradients

I have an american football pitch created purely by CSS. I have a sandbox in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/clattenburgcake/pen/WNjvmZd) and below is the code (I'm using ReactJS).

Basically, what I would like to do is to turn each `-webkit-linear-gradient` into a button, which upon clicking, will log its position on the console. Each of them represents a pitch position (there should be 101, as there are 99 pitch positions with the other two being the home and away end zones). Example diagram below.

I'm able to log the endzones easily as they are both unique spans, but I'm not sure how to do this with the other pitch positions. Here's my react code:

```
function App() {
  const printEndzone = (isHome) => {
    isHome ? console.log("home endzone") : console.log("away endzone");
  };

  return (
    <div id="football">
      <span className="endzone" title="home endzone" onClick={() => printEndzone(true)}>
      </span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="10"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="20"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="30"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="40"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="50"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="40"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="30"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="20"></span>
      <span className="yard" data-yard="10"></span>
      <span className="yard"></span>
      <span className="endzone" title="away endzone" onClick={() => printEndzone(false)}>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #d1d2d3;
}

body > div {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.middle {
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #120930;
  display: block;
}
#football {
  width: 70%;
  height: 420px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 55px #000;
  margin: auto;
}

#football span {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 8.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#football .endzone {
  background: #01a54f;
  width: 8.352%;
}

#football .endzone:last-of-type {
  background: #01652f;
  border-right: none;
}

#football::before,
#football::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 18.7%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 41%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#football::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 1px;
}

#football .endzone::before,
#football .endzone::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 3px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: -25%;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/

  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
}

#football .endzone::after {
  top: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

#football .endzone:last-of-type::before,
#football .endzone:last-of-type::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -25%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

#football .endzone:last-of-type::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
}

#football .yard {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      left,
      transparent 0,
      transparent 48.5%,
      #fff 48.5001%,
      #fff 51.5%,
      transparent 51.5001%
    ),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #01652f 0, #01652f 7%, transparent 7.1%, transparent
          9.5%, #01652f 9.6%, #01652f 17.6%, transparent 17.7%, transparent
          19.2%, #01652f 19.3%, #01652f 27.3%, transparent 27.4%, transparent
          29.9%, #01652f 30%, #01652f 38%, transparent 38.1%, transparent 40.6%, #01652f
          40.7%, #01652f 50%, #01a54f 50.001%, #01a54f 59.6%, transparent 59.7%, transparent
          62.3%, #01a54f 62.4%, #01a54f 70.4%, transparent 70.5%, transparent
          73%, #01a54f 73.1%, #01a54f 81.1%, transparent 81.2%, transparent
          83.7%, #01a54f 83.8%, #01a54f 91.8%, transparent 91.9%, transparent
          94.4%, #01a54f 94.5%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #01a54f 0,
        #01a54f 1.25%,
        #fff 1.2501%,
        #fff 4.76%,
        #01a54f 4.7601%,
        #01a54f 35%,
        #fff 35.0001%,
        #fff 38.51%,
        #01a54f 38.52%,
        #01a54f 65%,
        #fff 65.01%,
        #fff 68.51%,
        #01a54f 68.52%,
        #01a54f 95.23%,
        #fff 95.24%,
        #fff 98.74%,
        #01a54f 98.75%
      ) no-repeat 37px 0,
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #01652f 0, #01652f 1.25%, #fff 1.2501%, #fff
          4.76%, #01652f 4.7601%, #01652f 35%, #fff 35.0001%, #fff 38.51%, #01652f
          38.52%, #01652f 65%, #fff 65.01%, #fff 68.51%, #01652f 68.52%, #01652f
          95.23%, #fff 95.24%, #fff 98.74%, #01652f 98.75%);
}

#football .yard::before,
#football .yard::after {
  content: attr(data-yard) "\25C2";
  /*width: 20px;*/
  /*height: 20px;*/

  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  right: -24.5%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#football .yard::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 55px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(6)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(6)::after {
  content: attr(data-yard);
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(1)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(2)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(3)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(4)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(5)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(7)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(8)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(9)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(10)::before {
  content: "\25C2"attr(data-yard);
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(1)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(2)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(3)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(4)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(5)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(7)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(8)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(9)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(10)::after {
  content: attr(data-yard) "\25B8";
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(7)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(7)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(9)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(9)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(8)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(8)::after,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(10)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(10)::after {
  right: -60.5%;
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(11)::before,
#football .yard:nth-of-type(11)::after {
  content: "";
  width: 743px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 64%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    transparent 0,
    transparent 31px,
    #fff 32px,
    #fff 42px,
    transparent 43px,
    transparent 69px,
    #fff 70px,
    #fff 80px,
    transparent 81px,
    transparent 106px,
    #fff 107px,
    #fff 117px,
    transparent 117px,
    transparent 143px,
    #fff 144px,
    #fff 154px,
    transparent 155px,
    transparent 179px,
    #fff 180px,
    #fff 190px,
    transparent 191px,
    transparent 217px,
    #fff 218px,
    #fff 228px,
    transparent 229px,
    transparent 255px,
    #fff 256px,
    #fff 266px,
    transparent 267px,
    transparent 292px,
    #fff 293px,
    #fff 303px,
    transparent 305px,
    transparent 329px,
    #fff 330px,
    #fff 340px,
    transparent 341px,
    transparent 367px,
    #fff 368px,
    #fff 378px,
    transparent 379px,
    transparent 404px,
    #fff 405px,
    #fff 415px,
    transparent 416px,
    transparent 442px,
    #fff 443px,
    #fff 453px,
    transparent 454px,
    transparent 478px,
    #fff 479px,
    #fff 489px,
    transparent 490px,
    transparent 515px,
    #fff 516px,
    #fff 526px,
    transparent 527px,
    transparent 552px,
    #fff 553px,
    #fff 563px,
    transparent 564px,
    transparent 591px,
    #fff 592px,
    #fff 602px,
    transparent 603px,
    transparent 627px,
    #fff 628px,
    #fff 638px,
    transparent 639px,
    transparent 664px,
    #fff 665px,
    #fff 675px,
    transparent 676px,
    transparent 700px,
    #fff 701px,
    #fff 711px,
    transparent 712px
  );
  right: 0;
}

#football .yard:nth-of-type(11)::before {
  right: 1px;
  top: 38%;
}

#football .endzone:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#football #popup {
  display: none;
}
#football .endzone:hover #popup {
  display: block;
}
```

Example of a pitch position:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the mouse position x,y in that pitch position from 0 - 10. From there, you can move onto change the onClick function to determine the current possession and their correct pitch position based possession.

```
import { MouseEvent } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const printEndzone = (
    event: MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>,
    marker: string | number
  ) => {
    const rect = (event.target as HTMLSpanElement).getBoundingClientRect();
    const x =
      ((event.clientX - rect.left) /
        (event.target as HTMLSpanElement).clientWidth) *
      10;
    const y =
      (event.clientY -
        rect.top / (event.target as HTMLSpanElement).clientHeight) *
      10;
    console.log(x, y);
  };

  const markers = ["home", 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, "away"];

  return (
    <div id="football">
      {markers.map((marker, index) => (
        <span
          key={index}
          className={
            marker === "home"
              ? "endzone"
              : marker === "away"
              ? "endzone"
              : "yard"
          }
          onClick={(event) => {
            printEndzone(event, marker);
          }}
          data-yard={marker !== "yard" ? `${marker}` : ""}
        ></span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```